# Using AVPlayer in UITableView and Controller doesnt work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, avplayer

I created a app that is a music player.
I put UITableView in main screen and when user click a cell, New ViewController open and in it, I put pause and play and progress bar and other thing.
But when i back to tableview and select that cell again, progress bar and other thing value is 0.
How can i fix that ?
i Use [How to use AVPlayer in multiple view and resume controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021098/how-to-use-avplayer-in-multiple-view-and-resume-controls) to play song.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a judgment in didselect，if willPlay == playing, just do pushNextController else loadData And pushNextController

Comment: i didnt undrestand what should i do. are you saying to check playing ?